# GROUP_CONCAT to create a dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

My Query looks like so:

```
SELECT p.product_id, 
       Group_concat(DISTINCT Concat( optlan.option_label, ',', ovl.value) 
       SEPARATOR ';' 
       )                                                                     AS 
       options_01, 
       Concat(Group_concat(DISTINCT optlan.option_label), ';', 
       Group_concat(DISTINCT ovl.value))                                     AS 
       options_02, 
       Concat_ws(';', optlan.option_label, Group_concat(DISTINCT ovl.value)) AS 
       options_03 
FROM   products p 
       JOIN category c 
         ON p.category_id = c.category_id 
       LEFT JOIN options_categories opcat 
              ON opcat.category_id = c.category_id 
       LEFT JOIN options opt 
              ON opt.option_id = opcat.option_id 
       LEFT JOIN options_lang optlan 
              ON optlan.option_id = opt.option_id 
                 AND optlan.lang_id = 'NL' 
       LEFT JOIN option_values ov 
              ON ov.option_id = opt.option_id 
       LEFT JOIN option_values_lang ovl 
              ON ovl.value_id = ov.value_id 
                 AND ovl.lang_id = 'NL' 
WHERE  p.product_id = '25' 
GROUP  BY p.product_id;
```

options_01 result:

`option a,40;option a,50;option b,60;option b,70`

options_2 result:

`option a,option b;40,50,60,70`

and options_03:

`option b;60,70`

I would like to create this:

`option a;40,50|option b;60,70`

Or do I need to create it with PHP into the query ? Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Suspect, better to make processing  output data on php-side.Yes, thinking,of course it's possible to group how you want with mysql ( I don't know you tables`s structures), but it will be looking terrible and difficult for understanding.

Comment: @voodoo417 : The meaning is that  I combine labels with their values. Thus for example labels (option_a , option_b, etc...) and from table values (50, 60, 70, 80,....) wherin the first two are from option_a , so the outcome must be: (option_a;50,60|option_b;70,80|etcetera.......)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the structure of your db/tables, but i think you can modify your query like this (with all the modifications of your case):

```
        SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT(options_try SEPARATOR '|') as your_field
        FROM (
            SELECT
                CONCAT(optlan.option_label, ';', GROUP_CONCAT(ovl.value SEPARATOR ",")) AS options_try
            FROM
                products p
            JOIN category c
                ON p.category_id = c.category_id
            LEFT JOIN options_categories opcat
                ON opcat.category_id = c.category_id
            LEFT JOIN options opt
                ON opt.option_id = opcat.option_id
            LEFT JOIN options_lang optlan
                ON optlan.option_id = opt.option_id AND optlan.lang_id = 'NL'
            LEFT JOIN option_values ov
                ON ov.option_id = opt.option_id
            LEFT JOIN option_values_lang ovl
                ON ovl.value_id = ov.value_id AND ovl.lang_id = 'NL'
            WHERE
                p.product_id = '25'
            GROUP
                BY optlan.option_label;
        ) x1
```

Please, note the group at the end of the query. If you don't group your results by the "main" field, you can't use group_concat.

Comment: thanks for your help but your query gives an error. I do group by in my script.

Comment: Yeah it's normal, as i write i don't know the structure of the tables, so i can't test if it works. My answer will only explain how you can organize the filters, but the final mod must be made by you ;)

Comment: I understand what you mean, but is that case I will make my "problem" more clear. I try to explain below instead of this comment

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did make my question to complicate as I can do it more easy.

Suppose I have to tables:

Table 1: options => option_id and option_label
Table 2: values => value_id, option_id and value

```
CREATE TABLE `options` (
`option_id` int(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`option_label` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

CREATE TABLE `values` (
`value_id` int(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`option_id` int(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`value` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Table options:
    INSERT INTO `options` (`option_id`, `option_label`) VALUES
    (1, 'option a'),
    (2, 'option b');

Table values:
    INSERT INTO `option_values` (`value_id`, `option_id`, `value`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 'val 1a'),
    (2, 1, 'val 2a'),
    (3, 1, 'val 3a'),
    (4, 2, 'val 1b'),
    (5, 2, 'val 2b'),;

Now the query should look like so:

```
SELECT
 GROUP_CONCAT ........... AS all_options
FROM options o
JOIN values v
ON o.option_id = v.option_id
GROUP BY o.option_id
```

The outcome should be like this:

all_options
option a;val 1a,val 2a,val 3a|option b;val 1b,val 2b

Hope this makes sense.....